# ANSI Colors & Syntax

Tags: shell, colors, syntax-highlighting, ansi

Is there a mapping of ANSI colors to their syntax in a given shell?

For example, in BASH, Blue seems to be Folders and Green seems to be executable files.

Does a list exist for what ANSI colors mean in BASH, SSH, VI, etc.?

Comment: Most of it is customizable, too. Vim has a whole plethora of colorschemes on-line, if you're willing to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no universal mapping. `/etc/DIR_COLORS` or `~/.dir_colors` gives the colors that `ls` uses; for everything else, consult the relevant documentation.